# Upper Bound Estimation, Product of 2 Normal Distributions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, inequality, normal-distribution

I want to show that $(1-\Phi(x))(1-\Phi(y))\le\frac{xy}{xy-1}$ with  $x>0>y$.

I thought about using that $(1-\Phi(x))\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{x}e^{-\frac{-x^2}{2}}$ if $x>0$, but than i am getting problems with the fact that $y<0$ and the inequality is not holding anymore if i am using this estimate for x and -y.

Comment: This has little to do with [the product of two normal distributions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalProductDistribution.html), it has to do with the product of the CDFs of two normal distributions.

Answer (score 0):

The symmetry gives $(1-\Phi(x))(1-\Phi(y)) = \Phi(-x)\Phi(|y|)$ for $y < 0 <x$. However, this doesn't matter, because the proposed inequality doesn't hold.

When the magnitudes of $x$ and $y$ are small, the right hand side is also small, while the left hand side is very close to $1/4$.

For example, $x = \dfrac1{20}$ and $y = -\dfrac1{10}$, we have

$\qquad$the [left hand side](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=CDF%5BNormalDistribution%5B0,+1%5D,+1%2F20%5D+CDF%5BNormalDistribution%5B0,+1%5D,+-1%2F10%5D) $(1-\Phi(x))(1-\Phi(y)) \approx 0.239261$,

$\qquad$the right hand side $\dfrac{x y }{ xy - 1} = \dfrac1{201} \approx 0.00497512$.

How about a modified version $(1-\Phi(x))(1-\Phi(y))\overset{?}{\leq}\dfrac14 - \dfrac{x y }{ xy - 1}$. Too bad, this doesn't hold either. At $x = \dfrac1{10}$ and $y = -\dfrac1{10}$,

$\qquad$the [left hand side is](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=CDF%5BNormalDistribution%5B0,+1%5D,+1%2F10%5D+CDF%5BNormalDistribution%5B0,+1%5D,+-1%2F10%5D) $(1-\Phi(x))(1-\Phi(y)) \approx 0.248414$

$\qquad$the new right hand side is $\dfrac14 - \dfrac1{101} \approx 0.240099$

---

Could it be that by $\Phi(x)$ you actually mean the error function $\mathrm{Erf}(x)$? Note that the CDF of standard Normal is $\Phi(x) = \dfrac12 \left( 1 + \mathrm{Erf}\bigl( \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \bigr) \right)$

Please let me know if I misunderstood your question.